# What's the distribution? NB or Geo?

Tags: statistics

I'm struggling with the following exercise:

(Sorry for possible mistranslations, the exercise isn't in English)

*Due to the emergence of a highly contagious and spreading virus, an alert notice has been
issued to the population. In order to assess the probability of an individual becoming infected, individuals from this population are randomly selected until an already infected individual is observed. Assume that each individual has the same probability of being infected. So, the random variable Y is defined as the number of individuals observed until the interruption of selection. Consider n independent realizations of Y , presenting the following results:*

[image]

*a) Suppose a proper distribution to explain this example.*

*b) Use the Method of Moments to find the estimate(s) of the parameter(s) of this distribution.*

So, the problem is that I'm not sure if Y~Geo(p) or Y~NB(50,p), cause I don't know if a should analyze every event as a Geometric(cause they're independent) or analyze all together as a sum of Geometric(then a Negative Binomial) since we needed r=50 successes(infections) to stop the experiment. If it's a Geometric, letter B is simple cause E(x)=1/p, so we just need to find the mean. But if it's a NB, I don't how to proceed because of "r".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution that models the random variable $Y$, which corresponds to a single observation in the table, is geometric, because you keep selecting until you observe the first infected individual.  So $Y = 6$ means the sixth person selected was the first one that you saw was infected.  In the table, there is exactly $1$ such occurrence of $Y$.

(Note that a geometric random variable is a special case of a negative binomial random variable, such that the number of successes that need to be observed before stopping is $1$.)

To use the table to estimate the parameter $p$, the method of moments would simply involve comparing the sample mean $\bar Y$ to the theoretical mean of the geometric distribution.

The sample **total**, $n \bar Y = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, has a negative binomial distribution; that is to say, the sampling distribution of the sample total is negative binomially distributed.  But you do not need to know this to estimate $p$.